# Отрисовка кликабельных квадратов в View Android

Tags: java, android, canvas

Каким образом можно отрисовать динамически фигуры типа квадрат в View
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть view на активити я его получаю

```
View myview = (View)findViewById(R.id.myview);
```

Далее нужно отрисовать такие квадраты как на скриншоте и записать в этот view а не задавать setContentView для всего активиити. Подскажите статьи или классы, которые мне помогут в этом.

Начал понемногу разбираться :

```
public class OverlayView extends View {

public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(this.Hall == null)
        return;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(10+50+10, 10, 50, 50, paint);
}
}

<applicationcinema.com.cinema.UI.OverlayView
            android:id="@+id/hall_plan_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/standard_background" />
```

Почему то второй черный квадратик не рисуется, такое ощущение что функцию drawRect можно вызвать только 1 раз.

Comment: Можно создать `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: В чем различие ?

Comment: Если Вам нужно добиться того результата, что на картинке, то проще будет использовать `RecyclerView`, чем рисовать вручную.

Comment: Есть какойто пример который поможет в моем деле для RecyclerView ? RecyclerView это не тоже самое что GridView ?

Comment: Например, https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/. Нет, `RecyclerView` это не то же самое, что `GridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `drawRect` принимает позиции сторон прямоугольника (`left, top, right, bottom`).
То есть третий и четвёртый параметры - это координаты правого нижнего угла, а не ширина и высота.
Удобнее будет использовать класс `Rect` в таком случае:

```
    // создаём квадрат 50х50
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    // сдвигаем вправо на 10
    rect.offset(10, 0); 
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    // сдвигаем дальше вправо на 50+10
    rect.offset(50 + 10, 0); 
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```